# Is f(G) uniform under the described condition in ECDSA?

Tags: elliptic-curves, dsa

In ECDSA, $f(G)=r$, where $r$ is the $$-coordinate of group element $G$. Now it is known that $f(G)$ is not uniform([Why isn't $f(G)$ uniform in ECDSA?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/88279/why-isnt-fg-uniform-in-ecdsa)). Then in which range $f(G)$ is uniform?

Let $\langle G\rangle$ be a cyclic group on the ECDSA elliptic curve with the generator $G$, and $S=\{x|f(W)=x,\forall W\in\langle G\rangle\}$. My question is: for any $W\overset{\\\$}{\leftarrow}\langle G\rangle$, is $f(W)$ uniform in $S$?

Comment: Hint: the question is _not_ an exact duplicate of the linked one, at least as understood in my [answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/88281/555). In the present question, $S$ is the set of $x$ actually reached by $f(W)$, when I answered about uniformity over the full base field (e.g. $[0,p)$ for secp256k1).

Comment: @fgrieu my mistake, for $F_p$ one needs $p$ points to have a trivial uniformity, though, such curves are not secure at all.

Comment: @fgrieu I have modified the title. How about now? The range just refers to the output of f.

Comment: In general, it is not uniform, that is why we apply hash to mitigate those...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$f$ is defined as a function from the Elliptic Curve group to the finite field used to define the curve, yielding the X coordinate of the point considered. For the purpose of that definition, I'll assume the neutral of the group law (aka point at infinity, and noted $\infty$) has coordinates $(z,z)$, with $z$ a fixed element of the field such that for $x=z$ the curve's equation has no solution $y$ (for all [standard curves over a prime field](https://www.secg.org/sec2-v2.pdf#section.2) $\mathbb F_p$, and AFAIK all others, we can take $z=0$, where $0$ is the field's neutral).

The set $S$ is the image of the whole group $\langle G\rangle$ by $f$, thus a subset of the field including $z$.

**$f$ is almost exactly uniform on $S$**: the set $S$ has $(n-1)/2$ elements where $n$ is the (prime) order of $\langle G\rangle$, and each element of $S$ except $z$ has precisely two antecedents by $f$, sharing the same X coordinate. $z$ has a single antecedent, and that's $\infty$.
From a cryptographic standpoint (thus with $n$ large enough that $\sqrt n$ is not enumerable), probability that an enumerable number of independent and uniformly random elements $W_i$ of $\langle G\rangle$ include $\infty$, collide, or have colliding $f(W_i)$ is negligible, and the $f(W_i)$ are (indistinguishable from) independent and uniformly random elements of $S$.

Argument: for a given $x$ in the field, the curve's equation becomes a fixed second degree equation, which in a finite field has zero, one or two distinct solutions. When $x\in S$, the case zero solutions occurs only for $x=z$, by definition of $f$ and $S$. The case of one solution does not happen for standard curves over a prime field (I know no exception for others¹, and if there was it would be exceptional anyway). That leaves two solutions as the only (or at least the overwhelmingly most common) case for $x\ne z$.

---

¹ That holds for curves with equation $y^2=x^3+ax+b$, which is the case for [ECDSA using a prime field](https://www.secg.org/sec1-v2.pdf#subsubsection.2.2.1). Proof that holds for any ECDSA curve, or refutation, are appreciated.

Comment: Regarding ¹: those are points with $y=0$ and have order 2. I think that since we are discussing ECDSA, which requires invertible $k$, it makes sense to define it on a large prime order subgroup (given by the generator), otherwise some $k$ might not be invertible. In such subgroups there are no order 2 points.

Comment: @Ruggero: I follow you for curves with equation $y^2=x^3+ax+b$, which is the case for [ECDSA using prime field](https://www.secg.org/sec1-v2.pdf#subsubsection.2.2.1). However these is also $y^2+x\,y=x^3+ax^2+b$, which is the case for [ECDSA using binary field](https://www.secg.org/sec1-v2.pdf#subsubsection.2.2.2).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I just missed the fact that an x corresponds to two group elements.

Comment: @fgrieu You are right, sorry I missed that.